# How do I write this command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, msbuild

I need the following to be copy. The problem is that is an UNC so I need to use pushd to change directory first. How can I write a oneliner to make this work?

```
<Exec Command="xcopy /Y /F /S /R /I bin\*.dll \\nas.rc.se\test\DLL\$(ProjName)\Latest\"/>
```

So I am after somthing like pushd xcopy.... but dont know how to write it to make it work. Is it possible?

Comment: what if you call a `.bat` file.It is possible to do this in one line but will be ugly.

Comment: I rather not use a bat file. If it is possible without it that would be better

Answer (score 3):

```
<Exec Command='cmd /c "pushd \\nas.rc.se\test\DLL\$(ProjName)\Latest\ & xcopy /Y /F /S /R /I bin\*.dll \\nas.rc.se\test\DLL\$(ProjName)\Latest\"'/>
```

in `xml` attributes can be defined both with `'` and `"` .This is needed because the parameter passed to the `cmd` needs `"`